Whether blowup lemma holds for the graph family case?
Blowup lemma is a fundamental and well-known result in the field of extremal graph theory which assserts that $\pi(G)=\pi(G(t))$ for any $t \in \mathbb{N}^*$ where $\pi(G)$ is the Turan density of the graph $G$ and $G(t)$ is the $t$-blowup of $G$.
I wonder whether the assertion holds for graph families? Precisely, let $\mathcal{F}$ be a (finite) family of graphs. For $t \in \mathbb{N}^*$, write $\mathcal{F}(t):=\{G(t):G \in \mathcal{F}\}$. Then can we deduce $\pi(\mathcal{F})=\pi(\mathcal{F}(t))$ holds for any $t$?
I know the proof of blowup lemma uses the supersaturation lemma, but it seems hard to generalize it to the graph family case or find any references.
Thanks in advance for any helps or comments.

The answer is yes, I believe. First you can adapt the proof of the supersaturation lemma to obtain a generalized Blowup Lemma afterwards. The Lemma should say:
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a finite family of $k$-graphs (i.e. $k$-uniform hypergraphs) with all members of the same size $m$. Then for all $\epsilon >0$ there exist $\delta, n_0 > 0$ s.t. if $G$ is a $k$-graph on $n>n_0$ vertices with $e(G) > (\pi(\mathcal F ) + \epsilon) \binom{n}{k}$, then $G$ contains at least $\delta \binom{n}{m}$ different copies of members of $\mathcal{F}$.
The assumption that all members of $\mathcal{F}$ have the same size will not matter in the end because given a finite family $F$ we may define the finite family $F'$ consisting of all members of $F$ with added isolated vertices to make them all equal in size. You can convince yourself that then $\pi(F) = \pi(F')$. The lemma above is a version of the so called supersaturation lemma, a proof of which you can find in this Survey by Keevash, that is follow the proof of Lemma 2.1.
Given this you will find a proof of the Blowup-lemma for a single graph in the same survey (Theorem 2.2). You can adapt this proof again to finite families $\mathcal{F}$ with all members of size $m$. It's basically the same proof. At one point you will have to color a graph $H$ with different colors corresponding to different ways of embedding copies of your family members into $H$, in order to adapt the proof you will have to use more colors here than $m!$, i.e. you will have to use $|\mathcal{F}|\cdot m!$ colors. I hope it is alright that I do not repeat the proofs here again in detail :)
I hope this answers your question. It should be noted that this approach will not work for infinite families. And I'm not even sure if a Blowup Lemma would be true in this case. Maybe someone else knows the answer to that.
